# Include common content from xml documentation file

Tags: sandcastle, xml-documentation

I am using Sandcastle to generate documentation for a project. In order to reference xml documentation file  `include` tag is used.

```
///<include file='xml_include_tag.doc' path='MyDocs/MyMembers[@name="test"]/*' />
public class Test
```

And I would like to reference some common content from this XML doc file. For example:

```
<MyDocs><MyMembers name="test">
        <summary>
           <include file='common.xml' path='MyDocs/MyMembers[@name="test"]/*' />
        </summary>
</MyMembers></MyDocs>
```

Obviously it does not work this way. What is the right way to do such things? Probably there is some extension for Sandcastle?

Comment: Are you trying to include an XML file from another included XML file? In your examples, it seems to me that the first include adds the second file, and from there you want to include 'common.xml'. Is that so?

Comment: I've made a test using Visual Studio 2012, and it does resolve includes on included files, so for me it works as expected. What results do you get when you do it?

Comment: @JorgePoveda, I get exactly the same include tag as in summary. Could you provide your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using MAML token files. Sandcastle resolves them without issues.

```
/// <summary>
/// <token>Token1</token>
/// </summary>
```